# CSS less with background image and gradient?

Tags: css, less

What is the most efficient way to write less for this so that it can create rules for all browsers?

```
CSS output:

background: url(../i/bg_lines7.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #555, #333) #333;
background: url(../i/bg_lines7.png), -moz-linear-gradient(left, #555, #333) #333;
..


CSS output:
background: #000, url(../i/bg_lines7.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #555, #333);
background: #000, url(../i/bg_lines7.png), -moz-linear-gradient(left, #555, #333);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use mixins.

```
.my-multi-browser-thing (@image,@gsc,@gec,@bfb) {
    background: url(../i/@image), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, @gsc, @gec) @bfb;
    background: url(../i/@image), -moz-linear-gradient(left, @gsc, @gec) @bfb;
    ... add more syntax variations ...
}

.my-multi-browser-thing ("bg_lines7.png",#555,#333);
```